# Rule for using which

Tags: phrase-usage

The first signs in six months of a pickup in consumer spending are emerging, **which reduces** the chances that the Federal Reserve will lower interest rates when it meets next month.

Should it be which reducing? If yes, then why?

Comment: **No.** The fact described in the first clause **reduces** (present tense) the chances...

Comment: No: if you want to use "reducing", you have to drop the "which", as in "The first signs in six months of a pickup in consumer spending are emerging, reducing the chances that ..."

Comment: "The sun is shining. It makes me hot." = "The sun is shining, which makes me hot." = "The sun is shining, making me hot."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The full sentence is grammatically correct.

> The first signs in six months of a pickup in consumer spending are
> emerging, which reduces the chances that the Federal Reserve will
> lower interest rates when it meets next month.

"Which" is numerically neutral, and can be used for either a singular subject or a plural subject.  This will be noticed in expressions like "which is" and "which are."  However, in the example sentence, "which" refers back to *"The first signs in six months of a pickup in consumer spending are emerging"*, **all** of which becomes the noun for which "which" acts as a pronoun in the dependent clause that it begins.

In other words, "which" acts as a pronoun for the idea that *signs of increased consumer spending are emerging.*

The clause begun by "which" as its subject requires a verb.  "Reduces" is that verb.  "Reducing" would not be the correct form, as it would require a verb of being to form a continuous tense, or else it is a gerund noun, and not a verb.